# JQueryUI dialog: delay open until success loading slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, image-preloader

I have a jQueryUI dialog loading a slideshow with an Ajax request.

How can I delay the `.dialog('open')` until all images are loaded?
(some mobile connections need some time to load all images)

**EDIT (2013-07-04) to clarify better the question:** this dialogbox loads and is ready before all images are downloaded. Which makes some slides change with either black or halfloaded images. What I would like is to start the slideshow only when the .jpg files are in the browsers cache.

```
var eld = $('<div style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');
eld.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        $(this).html('').load ("img_swiper.php?img_url="+url, function() {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
            eld.dialog('close');
        })
        });
    },        
    close: function(event, ui) {
        eld.remove();
    },
    modal: true,
    height: 385,
    width: 750
});
eld.dialog('open');
```

Comment: I think, you have to use the JQuery call back function, for more info http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Comment: No, in image load function

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your loading satrts when you open dialog, so if you delay its open nothing happens with loading. So if you want to load images before opening dialog box then you should not load div body inside open function.

I have not tested it but mabye somthing like that would work:
1. load body into hidden div
2. start interval for checker function to see when all images are loaded.
3. open dialog

```
var eld = $('<div style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');
eld.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {

    },        
    close: function(event, ui) {
        eld.remove();
    },
    modal: true,
    height: 385,
    width: 750
});

function IsImageOk(img) {
    // During the onload event, IE correctly identifies any images that
    // weren’t downloaded as not complete. Others should too. Gecko-based
    // browsers act like NS4 in that they report this incorrectly.
    if (!img.complete) {
        return false;
    }

    // However, they do have two very useful properties: naturalWidth and
    // naturalHeight. These give the true size of the image. If it failed
    // to load, either of these should be zero.

    if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // No other way of checking: assume it’s ok.
    return true;
}
//Function for checking all images
function chk_images(where)
{
    var img_count = $('img', where);
    var ok_count = 0;
    $('img', where).each(function(){
        if (IsImageOk($(this).get(0)) )
        {
           ok_count++;
        }
    });

    if (ok_count == img_count) return true;
    return false;
}

eld.html('').load ("img_swiper.php?img_url="+url, function() {
   //Set up checker function
   var interval = setInterval(function(){
         //Check images inside eld
         if (chk_images(eld))
         {
              //Stop futher checking
              clearInterval(interval);
              eld.dialog('open');
         }
   },1000);
   $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
         eld.dialog('close');
    });
});
```

If browser do not want to load images inside hidden div then you could move this div out of screen with absolute position and make it visible for loading porpouse. Something like eld.css({position:'absolute',top: '-1000px',left: '-1000px'});

Check Allso:

- http://www.sajithmr.me/javascript-check-an-image-is-loaded-or-not
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp